# Woocommerce products not showing after a product with many variations in the catalog

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a curious problem.
When I've a product with a lot of variations (for example 15 colors variations), in the catalog page, the next products are not displayed.
But if the product has for example 5 variations, works nice.
Has it happened to someone?
Any idea?

Thank you very much to all!

The page is: https://www.covertea.shop/shop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQDSP.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "not displayed", do you mean the images of those products? or all the listed product? I just enter the site and I can see all (8) products. https://imgur.com/Uxq0NtH

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.
Ok can you return to view this page? This is because I changed the variations color in the product for testing.
I mean that images and price are not displayed.
The page currently looks like this: https://imgur.com/La1YJod

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I can fix my problem.
The problem was in the loop product of catalog, when have more than "x" number of variations the product variation can't load all.
How to fix this problem?
I was change the array that return small images on the loop and now return 3 variations.
Thanks you very much to all!